# Error in DataGrid random behavior when scrolling in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I have a datagrid and its rows are colored based on certain condtions..There is a vertical scrollbar for my datagrid.. If the user scrolls the datagrid the index of the colored rows r getting changed.. For eg: if 2 row is colored if the user scrolls down and comes up the index of the colored row is getting messed up...

here is the code....

```
 dggeneralconfiguration.LoadingRow += new EventHandler<DataGridRowEventArgs>(grid1_LoadingRow);
                dggeneralconfiguration.UnloadingRow += new EventHandler<DataGridRowEventArgs>(grid1_UnloadingRow);
void grid1_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            ShowGeneralGrid c = e.Row.DataContext as ShowGeneralGrid;

            if (c.Status == false)
            {
                if (e.Row != null)
                {
                    e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    //e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
                }
            }
        }
        void grid1_UnloadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            ShowGeneralGrid c = e.Row.DataContext as ShowGeneralGrid;

            if (c.Status == false)
            {
                if (e.Row != null)
                {
                    e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    //e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never. ;-) . I too had similar kind of problem.. try assigning row background to null on unloading row event.

```
    private void dg_UnloadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Background = null;
    }
```